# Map function syntax for keys with spaces in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, syntax

I have the following dataset that I am trying to get values from, using JavaScript.

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
{companies.map(({ matches }) => (
  <Company
    key={matches}
    name={matches}
    symbol={matches}
  />
))}
```

I have tried to get the values by providing the key in the map function as follows:

```
 name={matches['2. name']}
```

My question is, what syntax should I be using to get a value where the key has spacing and full-stops?

Comment: You're correct in using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation). (but whatever API is returning an object with keys like that seems problematic at best).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is this:

```
companies.map(({ matches }) => { … })
               ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is saying that for each item in the `companies` array, use a property named `matches` (through parameter destructuring), which, from what you're showing, doesn't exist.

Instead, I think you meant this:

```
companies.map(( matches ) => { … });
// or shorter:
// companies.map( matches => { … });
```